# weather stripping wood piece replacement

Tags: patio, weatherstripping

In my house, the weatherstripping wood piece under the front door to the patio was worn out over the years, so I took it off, the problem is that I couldn't find a replacement. The wood piece is about 36 inch long and 1.5 inch wide, there is a slot along the wood so that a rubber strip attached to the door can fit in for better sealing.

The finished piece looks like in picture one:

[image]

and the damaged one (which I took it off) looks like this, you can clearly see the slot I was talking about. I went to homedepot but failed to find the proper replacement - can any one recognize this and let me know where I can purchase stuff like it?

[image]

Comment: Any similar size should work, might be aluminum/plastic now.  Have not seen wood base weather stripping for years, people too lazy to paint, just put it it down and be done with it.

Comment: @crip659, thank you very much! well then I'll proceed to look for aluminum/plastic ones.